# Comparing values in two Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have two Javascript objects, which both currently look like this:

```
x = {"43943": "4249", "349439": "84439", "9034": "349", "90343": "30230" }
y = {"349439": "3949230", "9034": "292", "43943": "93240", "90343": "30000" }
```

I am wondering if I could compare the values associated with the same key, and identify if the value in y is lower than that in x, and then print both values and the difference between them?

Sometimes, the same keys may not appear in each array.

Could anyone offer any suggestions? I'm not sure where to start with this one.

Comment: What should happen if some key is only in one object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through one object, see if any of its keys exist in the other and then print the result to the console:

```js
/*Log Helper*/ function log(msg){ document.write(msg + '<br />'); console.log(msg); }

function difference(a, b){
  return Math.abs( + (parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10)))
}

var x = {"43943": "4249", "349439": "84439", "9034": "349", "90343": "30230" }
var y = {"349439": "3949230", "9034": "292", "43943": "93240", "90343": "30000" }

Object.keys(x).forEach(function(k){
  if(y[k]){
    log('key: ' + k);
    log('result (x-y): ' + difference(x[k], y[k]));
  }
});
```

Comment: <pedant> `Math.abs( + (parseInt(x[k], 10) - parseInt(y[k], 10)))` </pedant> Difference between..

Comment: @Pogrindis Pedantic but true :) I amended it.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all properties in one object and perform the calculation if the requirements are met.

```js
function map(o, p) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        result[k] = result[k] || {};
        result[k][p] = +o[k];
        if (p === 'y' && result[k].y < result[k].x) {
            result[k].difference = result[k].x - result[k].y;
        }
    });
}

var x = { "43943": "4249", "349439": "84439", "9034": "349", "90343": "30230" },
    y = { "349439": "3949230", "9034": "292", "43943": "93240", "90343": "30000" },
    result = {};

map(x, 'x');
map(y, 'y');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```